# wcf netmsmq transactional service

Tags: wcf, transactions, msmq

Hy, all.

I have an interesting case. I have tried to create a wcf service-client communication based on netmsmq binding hosted on windows service app.
So I catch a problem with my host service - it can not receive any message from queue. MSDTC shows transaction rollback. And after some tries messages are moving into retry subqueue. ServiceHost become failed state and after i start in again in fails again and again. 
So in host application i have no exception and nothing except host fault state.
I have service with two contracts (if it is important).

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void Send1(MyDataContract data);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void Send2(MyDataContract data);
}
[DataContract]
public class MyDataContract
{
    [DataMember]
    public string From { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Host { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string To { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime SendTime { get; set; }
}
```

some service implementation

```
[OperationBehavior(TransactionScopeRequired = true, 
                 TransactionAutoComplete = true)]
public void Send1(MyDataContract dc)
{......}
```

service config:

<endpoint address="net.msmq://localhost/private/myservice" binding="netMsmqBinding" contract="IService" bindingConfiguration="NetMsmqBinding_IService" />

Messages are in queue - client service works fine.
So at runtime method Send1 of service host never executes. But i handle HostFaulted events close after moving message from retry subqueue to incoming queue. That's all i can say.

any help?

Comment: It is difficult to envision the problem from the description above. Please mention the fault along with the code if possible.

Comment: I've just add more imformation. Is it helpful?

Comment: Can you post the binding configuration for NetMsmqBinding_IService? I suspect that this is not set to Transactional where your queue has the transactional attribute set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, i spend around one day to detect the problem. So step by step:
1. I've got microsoft sample on msmq wcf
2. I found no difference
3. I understood, that i have big messages (larger 1Mb), so by default WCF can, not deserialize such big messages. It was neccessary to set **maxBufferPoolSize** and **maxReceivedMessageSize**

But that's the question - why wcf client successfuly send such big messages without any extended configurations :)

My advise: in WCF set package size and pools to max possible for you (if only you uses that service).